# Photoshop Monalisa Face Swap: Blending Skin Tone, reduce yellow

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blending

[image: Adding Ashwarya Rai's face to the Mona Lisa painting## Heading ##]

Hello

### GOAL: TO MAKE SKINTONE MATCH IN FACE AND NECK

Newbie. Just started learning Photoshop.

I have a practice exercise to modify the Mona Lisa in whatever way I want (just to practice.)
I decided to give her a celebrity's face.
I am using [this awesome Photoshop Training Channel Tutorial](https://youtu.be/gOQ25Kp6jPY).
I am adding [Ashwarya Rai](https://www.pinkvilla.com/entertainment/nostalgia/flashback-friday-when-aishwarya-rai-bachchan-confessed-she-detested-being-called-fake-and-called-it-unreal)'s face to the [Mona Lisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_Lisa) painting.

First, I

1. Increased the vibrance and saturation of the original image which looked too dull (perhaps a mistake)
2. Then I copied in Ash's face after a lasso selection.
3. Resize, move
4. Ctrl T to transform and warp, using right eye as my reference
5. Auto blend (Seamless fill and Content Aware checkboxes and Panorama selected)
6. Layer mask to clean up edges

> I notice  (channels) the Mona Lisa was mainly reds with yellow, almost
> no blue  Ash's face has more blue

I've tried fiddling with the image adjustments and layer adjustments.
**I want her face to blend in.**

*What should I do better?

- I can do over fixing the original image first
- Edit the face source and target Mona Lisa before swapping
  What should I do to make the faces match?
  What adjustments should I make this time round?*
  Thanks!

Comment: There's one odd thing about the Mona Lisa that your overlay makes even weirder… she already looks like her face is turned more 'towards camera' than the rest of her head. You overlay emphasises that still further. In more practical terms, get rid of your initial  'colour enhancements' entirely. It makes it look like a cartoon.

Comment: #1 aspect needed to blend things well.. **matching angles of source images**. Clearly the faces in the source images are not the same. You need to find a photo which **matches** the angle of the painting. You can't "fake", "force", or "correct" this aspect.. it all comes down to source material. After that.. color blending is comparatively *easy*.

Comment: @Scott, with the new Neural Filters in Photoshop you can actually turn the head slightly with a slider. Check [this video](https://youtu.be/5rIl2-Gw8lQ?t=152). It's still very experimental and I hate the idea and all, but it *is* somewhat possible. 

Comment: @Wolff - Wow, that's eerie. How to turn a human into a bad CGI figure in 3 easy steps ;)

Comment: That tutorial is not good at all. Matching the eyes is a total mistake. 1. The face is not just the eyes and mouth, but the overall shape and proportion of the head. 2. It is supposed to "match" the colors but as you can see, it did not, It is not about colors. It is about everything.

Comment: @Wolff ... thanks.. wow... and "ah crap"

Comment: Thanks all, for the comments. I will take care to choose source material that does as much work for me as possible and pay more attention to angles .

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do better?

One thing: **Observe**

And that is starting with your choice of starting material. Please, do not use a direct flash photo of a person... that is the ugliest light anyone can have.

Here is a search on the actress:

[image]

Which image has the best potential to match the intended usage?

A. Matching angle

**B. Matching light**

Gosh, even the hairstyle matches!

[image]

Answer: Observe

---

Now, to answer the 2 questions about color.

**1. Reducing the yellow**

That color is probably now an intrinsic part of the look of the Monalisa. Yes, they are not the original colors, it is hundreds of years old... but the exercise probably intends to make it look like a renaissance painting, so, keep it to some extent.

Simply use curves and... **observe**.

Yellow is the opposite of blue, and as the painting is dark, I do not want to reduce the red and green, so I will rise a bit the channel blue.

[image]

Done. The image less yellow but still looks old and natural.

---

**2. Match the photo to the overall tone of the painting**

Well, let's try just the opposite, reduce the blue instead of rising it.

[image]

Observe that I did not use a curve, just a straight line, that is because I want to reduce the white from the eyes. The painting does not have white for the eyes.

I still need to adjust some things. Reducing the green so the image looks a bit more magenta.

[image]

And rising the dark point. I need to raise the red a bit more to give it a brownish tone.

[image]

---

I adjusted a bit more the curves on both layers.

**I am doing very lazy work**. But even without doing any blending,  masking nor scaling, the project looks promising... weird, but promising.

[image]

The point, again, is NOT a recipe, the only real recipe is: **Observe**, and based on that, make decisions...

---

An additional note:

Do not match a face based on the eyes and mouth position. I was tempted to use transparency to "match" but that is a mistake.

The only way to match the scale and position is to **observe** the image and **feel it right**.

Comment: Hi @Rafael Thank you for all the tips! Exactly what I was hoping for. I will redo this project with your feedback in mind, and observe more.